# Java JTextField special chars

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, jtextfield, file-encodings

I have a problem with the chars of all JTextField on my program (when compiled into JAR).
When I run it from Eclipse everything works fine... the problem is when run from the already compiled JAR.

The problem is, when I insert text to JTextField with special character as "**Ñandú?**" when java extract text from the input that goes with rare characters.
For example: `System.out.println( myTextField.getText() );`. That would write in the console: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PogD7.png)

I have tried all kinds of way to switch chars, but when I write again on the console or in the interface reappear rare signs. I've even tried the library `Commons Lang 3.1`, but I have not been successful :(

I hope someone knows what to do! The only way to work is inserting `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` on running the jar file, but that can not be so.

Sorry for the English. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the default encoding for your computer, which for Windows would be C16 and doesn't support unicode. Run your program with the following command in terminal:

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 <path to your .jar>
```

Eclipse would run your applications like so if you have any unicode in your document, but outside of it, you're on your own.

The only other possible way I can think of is writing a .bat script with this command and putting it in the same folder as the application.

Comment: Of course, as I said it works well in this way, but the idea is that no need to insert that command. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that in your question. Editing

Comment: No problem, thanks for the idea, I'll think maybe last stay remain so with .bat or Launch4J.

Comment: No way to add this option from METAINF?